# Failed to startup Jboss 5.1

Tags: jboss

I am on `Redhat`, using `Jboss 5.1` I am not able to start my Jboss. previously it was working i added some jar file in lib. Now its throwing error saying

```html
    Failed to boot JBoss:
    java.lang.NullPointerException
     at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:136)
     at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What can be the possible cause of this ???

Comment: How about try removing those jars from the lib folder and instead package it with your app since they are not provided by the container?

Comment: hahaha.. I replaced the whole bin folder